# RPi 4 CEC-Client with LG TV, switch from TV tuner?

Tags: cec-client

So I have managed to control the LG TV (Simplink Enabled) with the `cec-client` library on the RPi 4.

The problem is when I turn the TV back on, it defaults to the TV tuner input.

There is no TV aerial connected and I have had a look through the LG TV's settings but could not find anyway to set the default input to HDMI.

- Simplink is enabled
- RPi is connected to HDMI1
- Connection is set as PC

Is there a way with the cec-client to tell the TV to use HDMI 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "as" command sets the RPi to the active source, which tells the TV to use the port the RPi is on.

Give this a try:

Turn TV on:

```bsh
echo "on 0" | cec-client RPI -s -d 1
```

Set active source:

```bsh
echo "as" | cec-client RPI -s -d 1
```

For a particularly stubborn monitor I created the following "tvon.sh" script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
echo "on 0" | /usr/bin/cec-client &
cecpid=$!
echo $cecpid
sleep 15s
kill $cecpid
echo "on 0" | /usr/bin/cec-client &
cecpid=$!
echo $cecpid
sleep 15s
kill $cecpid
echo "as" | /usr/bin/cec-client &
cecpid=$!
echo $cecpid
sleep 15s
kill $cecpid
```